# Cannot get the action bar to support Android 2.3 (Currently using 4.4 version)

Tags: android

Working on 4.4 version. Got the action bar to work on 4.4. But when tried to run the same code on Android 2.3, action bar disappears. Please anyone walk me through this. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: action bar is not supported for lower versions.. u cud use sherlock action bar, or android support v7

Comment: Ask Jake Wharton about his masterpiece

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to use the [ActionBarCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) in the support library, since it's officially maintained by the Android team.  In the link I've provided, they also give you the source to the I/O 2013 app which shows you how to use this class

ActionBarSherlock is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Use [Actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library to fix this issue . It support for v2.3 to v4.4 .

Note* to execute this in v2.3 Change the theme of your application in manifest file to .

```
android:theme="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

if i remember well ActionBar Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11).

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

But if you try to use it in lower version like 2.3 you can use (ActionBarSherlock) this:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html

Check android version to use a combination

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the support library by Google for adding ACTIONBAR in lower versions. The support library can be downloaded from the SDK Manager. Go to `SDK Manager --> Extras --> Android` Support library.